Running Laravel Sail under Windows using Docker Desktop
I have been using Linux for a very long time. Now I had to go back to Windows and I have a problem with Docker, specifically Docker Desktop. It is necessary for me to run sail, to which I am strongly accustomed .On Admin I ran it without any problem. The problems started on the user account. When launching Docker Desktop I get the error
deploying WSL2 distributions
ensuring main distro is deployed: checking if main distro is up to date: checking main distro bootstrap version: getting main distro bootstrap version: open Docker-desktop: The network name cannot be found.
checking if isocache exists: CreateFile \wsl$docker-desktop-data: The network name cannot be found.

I found a solution, but it is not optimal. Namely - first I have to run powershell with admin privileges and type the command:
 wsl --unregister docker-desktop
Only Docker Desktop starts up correctly. Do you have any idea how to fix this?
I installed Docker Desktop and WSL classically, according to the instructions.
The only thing I have been able to find is to use the command described above in powershell, but this is a temporary solution. Doing this every time I want to start a project is fudging.
